# Graph Theory (Edges and coloring)

Tags: graph-theory

Show that $e(G) ≥ \binom{χ(G)}{2}$ for every graph G.

Here, $e(G)$ represents the number of edges in the graph.

Comment: Suppose $G$ is colored using the fewest number of possible colors, and then choose any two of those colors (say, blue and red). Can you see why there must be an edge connecting some red vertex to some blue vertex? (The word _fewest_ is key).

Comment: What is $\chi(G)$? is it the Euler characteristic or a coloring function or something?

Comment: χ(G) is the chromatic number of the Graph G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color $G$ using $\chi_G$ colors. For each pair of colors used (say, blue and red), there must be some edge connecting a red vertex to a blue one. If not, then recoloring all red vertices blue would result in a valid coloring with $\chi_G-1$ colors, contradicting the definition of $\chi_G$. Thus, for each pair of colors, we get a distinct edge in $G$, showing that the number of edges is at least $\binom{\chi_G}2$.